# How to preserve colored output (stdout and stderr) for cmd scripts from powershell?

Tags: powershell, cmd

We have build scripts for cmd. For example here is output of one of them.

[image: Colored output of build script from cmd]

When I run same commands in PS it outputs everything in red (probably because it's for err output).

[image: Red output of powershell]

Can I keep colors somehow?

Answer (score 4):

At first, I didn't think it was possible.

But, after a little searching I found this blog post, [Colorized capture of console screen in HTML and RTF](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/colorized-capture-of-console-screen-in-html-and-rtf/).

You should be able to use the PowerShell script from there to create what you need.

Comment: Nice! Still need some work to do, but it looks like I can create a wrapper that preserve colors.

Comment: After trying a couple of small examples, I can't reproduce the behavior you're seeing.  If you can provide a simple repro, I'll dig further for you.

Comment: @JasonShirk What can't you reproduce?

Comment: With a trivial C# console app, write colored output to both stdout and stderr.  Call this exe directly from PowerShell and from a bat file called from PowerShell.  Both ways colors look the same as if called from cmd.

Comment: @JasonShirk I'm not following what you're saying. xvorsk wants to capture the colors of the output, not just the text of the output.

Comment: @aphoria The output turned red when run from PowerShell.  I can't reproduce that.

Comment: Actually, I think _I've_ misunderstood the question. I thought he wanted to capture the colors of the outputted text. Really he is asking why the colors do not show up when called from PowerShell.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not positive this will work, but if you don't mind redirecting stderr to stdout, PowerShell won't try to color everything red.  To do this, just add 2>&1 when you run your cmd script, e.g.

```
build.cmd 2>&1
```

Comment: Thank you, I already tried it - doesn't work for me. Looks like we have a lot of subscripts/exe/powershell subcalls and 2>&1 doesn't work for nested calls.

Comment: Just surround it with quotes to pass the redirection to cmd.exe: `"2>&1"`