# Is there a way to preserve ANSI control codes in PowerShell command output?

Tags: string, powershell, ansi-colors

In PowerShell, is there a way to preserve the ANSI control codes used to convey color information to the console when assigning a program's output to a variable?

For instance, I use Test Kitchen which provides colored output unique to each suite of tests to run. When I run `kitchen create INSTANCE`, I get output in several colors. However, if I assign the output to a variable, or pipe it to another cmdlet such as `Tee-Object`, that color information is lost. It seems that PowerShell strips this information out when the result is sent down the pipeline or assigned to a variable:

```
kitchen create INSTANCE           # Colored output

$output = kitchen create INSTANCE
Write-Host $output                # Color information is lost
```

Curiously though, I can implement control codes in my own strings and PowerShell is able to honor them when Virtual Terminal is enabled. These survive variable assignment, unlike command output:

```
$output = "`u{001b}[31mHello"
Write-Host $output                # Results in colored output
```

So it seems that the color information is being stripped out only from a program's output, and only if the value is assigned or sent down the pipeline. Is there a way to preserve these control codes from external commands?

Comment: I'm not confident how it works in the PowerShell ecosystem, but in Unix-like systems, it's often the command itself that detects whether output is to a terminal, and switches off colour control codes.

Comment: PowerShell is not to blame here. Most utilities (external programs) that are capable of colored output via ANSI escape sequences at least _by default_ apply coloring _selectively_, namely only when stdout is connected to a _terminal_ (i.e. when printing to the display). Such utilities may offer opt-in mechanisms to apply coloring _unconditionally_, via command-line options and/or environment variables.

Comment: depending on how much output you have, and what you're trying to do with it, maybe you can have the output assign a tag to itself. for example. `[pscustomobject]@{type="error";output=$results}` this way you can work with the object with a foreach loop and switch/if cases... and if you just want the output, you could do `write-host $results.output` you could even have a parameter switch that says `kitchen create instance -colorTag` which could enable the tagging feature but i'm not sure what language your kitchen function/command is written in. instead of type="error" you could do color="red"

Comment: @mklement0 I was afraid of this. I used TK as my example although that does have an option to provide unconditional colors. However, many utilities which provide color output don't, as you mentioned. I was hoping I might either be able to change the behavior during variable assignment at least, or write a module to assist with preserving console colors, to cover utilities which do not offer a `force-color` option.

Comment: See also: [PowerShell output with color redirected to file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76864508/1701026)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To add to [your own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72264244/45375):

- On *Windows* I'm not aware of any simple solutions, though perhaps there is a programmatic way to do what the `script` utility does on Unix-like platforms (see next point).
- On *Unix-like platforms*, you can use the [`script`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/script.1.html) utility to make external programs believe they are connected to a terminal and thus make them produce colored output they would otherwise suppress:

  - `script` is not a POSIX-mandated utility, but it ships with at least some Linux distros, notably Ubuntu, as well as with macOS.
  - Notably, the macOS and Linux implementations use *different syntax*, as shown below.

Example:

- Note:

  - `ls --color=auto` is used as a readily available test command, because it exhibits the *conditional* coloring behavior.
  - `ls --color=always` would exhibit *unconditional* coloring behavior, and would therefore obviate the need for `script` - as such, `ls` is an example of a utility that *does* allow you to request unconditional coloring; `ls --color=auto` merely serves as a stand-in for utilities that do not.
  - The variable assignment below (`$out = ...`) is enclosed in `(...)` in order to pass the value being assigned *through*, so you'll see right away that the coloring is preserved.
- Linux

```bash
($out = script -qc 'ls --color=auto' /dev/null)
```

- macOS:

```bash
($out = script -q /dev/null ls --color=auto)
```

Comment: Interestingly enough, I did find [this answer on Super User](https://superuser.com/a/662185/85636). I don't know if `script.exe` is available standalone anywhere but that user reports it can be moved out of `cygwin` and run independently. Now, whether it handles all of the features the same way as in Unix is another story, but might be an avenue worth looking into.

Comment: Thanks, @BendertheGreatest - if you're willing to explore this and report back, I'm happy to update the answer. Even if it works, though, having to install cygwin seems like a lot of effort.

Comment: If I ever explore this I will. I imagine if it's available in cygwin there perhaps is a consumable package (pacman, perhaps, if msys2 can install the same util) which the utility could be obtained from.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using this on PowerShell v7.3.3 and haven't tested on older versions of 7. I'm pretty sure this won't work for PowerShell 5 since that doesn't have $PsStyle

```
# Get the current setting so you can flip it back if needed
$OriginalValue = $PsStyle.OutputRendering

# this output should be color coded
$PsStyle.OutputRending = "Ansi"
$String = Get-ChildItem | Select -First 3 | Out-String
Write-Host $String

# this output should not be color coded
$PsStyle.OutputRendering = "Host"
$String = Get-ChildItem | Select -First 3 | Out-String
Write-Host $String

# this should be back to your default/original behavior
$PsStyle.OutputRendering = $OriginalValue
$String = Get-ChildItem | Select -First 3 | Out-String
Write-Host $String
```

Comment: Got "The property 'OutputRending' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists and can be set." on PS 7.3.6

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by [@IMSoP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72263942/is-there-a-way-to-preserve-ansi-control-codes-in-powershell-command-output?noredirect=1#comment127670843_72263942) and [@mklement0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72263942/is-there-a-way-to-preserve-ansi-control-codes-in-powershell-command-output?noredirect=1#comment127670872_72263942) in the question comments, the problem does not lie within PowerShell. To quote [@mklement0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72263942/is-there-a-way-to-preserve-ansi-control-codes-in-powershell-command-output?noredirect=1#comment127670872_72263942):

> PowerShell is not to blame here. Most utilities (external programs) that are capable of colored output via ANSI escape sequences at least by *default* apply coloring *selectively*, namely only when stdout is connected to a *terminal* (i.e. when printing to the display). Such utilities may offer opt-in mechanisms to apply coloring *unconditionally*, via command-line options and/or environment variables.