# How to capture output in a log and have it printed to terminal in the original formatting in C# .Net program

Tags: c#, .net, powershell

I have the following code:

```cs
ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo()
{
    FileName = "powershell",
    Arguments = $"-NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command \"cd '{strLocation}'; & 'application.exe' 2>&1 | Tee-Object -File '{tempLogFilePath}'; Read-Host 'Press Enter to close...'\"",
    UseShellExecute = false,
    CreateNoWindow = false, // Show the terminal window
};
```

This works well, except the output printed to the terminal is without colors. The application.exe, when run without redirection to log file, prints a lot of output in multiple colors, making it very easy to read:

See image:
[image: My application with color text when run in powershell]

However, with the redirection to a log file and the terminal, the output to the terminal lost all its formatting, including the colors.

How can I implement a similar functionality (to save the output to log and to show it to the terminal) but have the output to the terminal preserve its formatting?

Note: if there is a better solution but with using a different terminal other than powershell, then I am open to that option.

Comment: Try making the -File an RTF instead of TXT or LOG

Comment: @jdweng I'm not trying to save the formatting in the log file, but rather in the terminal window.

Comment: A terminal window does not have color.  It is only black and white.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46016763/powershell-output-color-for-certain-results

Comment: @jdweng I don't agree. I added to the question a screenshot showing my application output in powershell terminal with color text. That's what I want to maintain. Here's the link to the screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/M7kAP.png

Comment: I would like to recreate your situation.  Is this in Visual Studio's C#?  Is this a "Console App" or "Console App (.NET Framework)"?

Comment: @Darin this is a console app project using .Net framework 4.7.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **problem** is most likely *not* your invocation via PowerShell / the .NET process APIs, but **behavior built into the application you're launching**:

- **Many utilities**, especially those with a Unix heritage, ***vary their output-formatting behavior depending on whether their stdout stream is connected to a terminal (console)* or not**, and *only if so* do they employ formatting (coloring) via [VT (Virtual Terminal)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-virtual-terminal-sequences) escape sequences (aka ANSI escape sequences).<sup>[1]</sup>
- Thus, given your use of [`Tee-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/tee-object) of necessity *redirects* the target application's stdout stream in order to be able to *capture* it, **you need to make your application emit VT/ANSI escape sequences *unconditionally***:

  - On ***Unix*-like platforms**, you can would be able to use the **[`script`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/script.1.html) utility**, which ships with most platforms, to make external programs believe they are connected to a terminal and thus make them produce colored output they would otherwise suppress - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72264735/45375) for an example.
  - On ***Windows*, there is no built-in solution**, so your **options** are:

    - Consult the target application's documentation to see if there's an *opt-in* way to request that VT sequences be emitted *unconditionally*, which could take the form of a *CLI option* (e.g.,`--color=always`) or possibly an *environment variable*.
    - Look for a Windows analog to the Unix `script` utility (I don't know if there is one; [this SuperUser answer](https://superuser.com/a/662185/139307) may or may not be helpful) or investigate a custom solution (which - if even possible at all - will likely require low-level WinAPI calls).

---

<sup>[1] The design rationale is that if stdout output is *captured*, the capturer is likely only interested in *data*, for *programmatic processing*, and not also in formatting escape sequences that primarily benefit the *human observer*.</sup>